# Export button in Eclipse CDT “Paths and Symbols” dialog?

Tags: eclipse, reference, header, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem concerning referenced projects and I need to ask this question.
This has already been asked here ["Export" button in Eclipse CDT "Paths and Symbols" dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790631/export-button-in-eclipse-cdt-paths-and-symbols-dialog) but I consider the answer to this old question to be unsatisfactory (could be my bad, though) so I am kindly asking for someone to further clarify.

What is the logic of a dependee project 'exporting' one of its own include paths to dependent projects? In what way is this needed?

I am asking this because I am unable to make Eclipse properly detect changes in dependee projects and perhaps this is related. See [Eclipse CDT not building project on header file change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884827/eclipse-cdt-not-building-project-on-header-file-change)

Thanks and sorry if this is weird but I believe a clarification is in order.